# Powershell Commands to CSV Using Redirect - Exclude 2nd Row

Tags: python, powershell, csv, batch-file

I am currently using an append redirect command ( csv >> MyFile.csv ) to loop through multiple power shell commands in a single batch file. The problem I am having is that each command brings back column headers so when they get appended to the CSV the data is intermittently interrupted by the headers. I am using the following code in my batch file:

```
python get_samplemetric1_daily.py --pkgs samplemetric1 --country_code 
samplecountry --date_from 2015-01-01 --date_to 2017-01-01 --format csv > MyFile1.csv

python get_samplemetric2_daily.py --pkgs samplemetric2 --country_code 
samplecountry --date_from 2015-01-01 --date_to 2017-01-01 --format csv >> MyFile1.csv
```

And am attempting to use the select -skip 1 command to eliminate the column headers, however I keep receiving the following error:

```
error: unrecognized arguments: select -skip 1
```

I can't figure out for the life of me how to integrate this into my code. If anyone has any suggestions or advice it would be greatly appreciated as this is the last disruption that is holding back my final product. Below are two examples of how I have attempted to integrate select -skip 1 into my code.

```
python get_samplemetric2_daily.py select -skip 1 --pkgs samplemetric2 --country_code 
samplecountry --date_from 2015-01-01 --date_to 2017-01-01 --format csv >> MyFile1.csv
```

and

```
python get_samplemetric2_daily.py --pkgs samplemetric2 --country_code samplecountry 
--date_from 2015-01-01 --date_to 2017-01-01 --format csv  select -skip 1 >> MyFile1.csv
```

Comment: You are mixing Python, batch and PowerShell. I guess you could generate the CSV file with Python and then "correct" it with PowerShell? There must be a one-line solution to this but that may not be the best idea to use it.

Comment: Thanks sodawillow, the reason the syntax is mixed is because the code is a using a Python API to call data and is technically being run in Powershell, however in order to loop through all instances that I need I am using a batch file. With that, said I think a batch command should be able to do the trick. Do you happen to know a simple batch command to delete the first line before exporting the CSV?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a `|` before `select`

Comment: Why don't you insert a `|more +1 >> MyFile1.csv` when using cmd.exe.

Comment: LotPings - That worked perfectly. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this question was provided in the comments by LotPings.

I needed to add the following:

```
|more +1
```

within the following context:

```
csv |more +1 >> MyFile1.csv
```